# zmq.hpp fails assertion when attempting to debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, zeromq

Its been a while since I worked with c++ in visual studio, and due to this I can't tell when I am doing wrong when attempting to run a debug instance of zmq's hello world client.

After installing zmq 4.0.3 and downloading the zmq.hpp master branch from github I copy/pasted the hello world client from the zmq guide.

Using Visual Studio 2010

I navigated to the project properties and have included both the include folder containing zmq.h and the folder including zmq.hpp

I also included the lib folder under the linker->general->additional library dependencies, and I added the libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_3.lib file to the linker->input->additional dependencies.

I have also included the libzmq-v100-mt-gd-4_0_3.dll in the Debug folder for the project.

After cleaning the project the code compiled fine when selecting Build->Build Solution and Build->Compile, but when I run a debug instance I get an assertion failed at line 276 resulting in an abort.

I don't understand why this is happening and could use some help figuring out what I need to fix to run the example.

**UPDATE**

I changed the c++ code to c code without changing anything else and I was able to compile and run without issue.

The assertion being failed is rc==0 at line 267 of the zmq.hpp file which is the second assertion in this code snippet.

```
inline explicit context_t (int io_threads_, int max_sockets_ = 1024)
{
    ptr = zmq_ctx_new ();
    if (ptr == NULL)
        throw error_t ();

    int rc = zmq_ctx_set (ptr, ZMQ_IO_THREADS, io_threads_);
    ZMQ_ASSERT (rc == 0);

    rc = zmq_ctx_set (ptr, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS, max_sockets_);
    ZMQ_ASSERT (rc == 0);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted what the assertion was.

Comment: I made an update to the post to include what the assertion is.