# Is changing a C project to a C++ project as simple as including the related .hpp file

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, zeromq

This question is related to [zmq.hpp fails assertion when attempting to debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335467/zmq-hpp-fails-assertion-when-attempting-to-debug) as I am not getting any answers.

I have a C project running in visual studio 2010 that works as expected. I created a new project with C++ code taken from the same author of the C project and set the C++ project up the same way as the original C project. The only change I made to the set up is I also included the related .hpp file for the C++ project.

The C++ project builds fine, but fails assertions when it is run. Am I setting the C++ project up correctly, or do I need to do something else?

**Update**

The C code that works

```
// C Hello World client
#include <zmq.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("Connecting to hello world server...\n");
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");

    int request_nbr;
    for (request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        char buffer [10];
        printf ("Sending Hello %d...\n", request_nbr);
        zmq_send (requester, "Hello", 5, 0);
        zmq_recv (requester, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received World %d\n", request_nbr);
    }
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

The C++ code that compiles but fails assertion in zmq.hpp

```
//
// Hello World client in C++
// Connects REQ socket to tcp://localhost:5555
// Sends "Hello" to server, expects "World" back
//
#include <zmq.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    // Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    // Do 10 requests, waiting each time for a response
    for (int request_nbr = 0; request_nbr != 10; request_nbr++) {
        zmq::message_t request (6);
        memcpy ((void *) request.data (), "Hello", 5);
        std::cout << "Sending Hello " << request_nbr << "…" << std::endl;
        socket.send (request);

        // Get the reply.
        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv (&reply);
        std::cout << "Received World " << request_nbr << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The block of code where the assertion is failing in the zmq.hpp header at line 267. The assertion that is failing is the second assertion.

```
inline explicit context_t (int io_threads_, int max_sockets_ = 1024)
{
    ptr = zmq_ctx_new ();
    if (ptr == NULL)
        throw error_t ();

    int rc = zmq_ctx_set (ptr, ZMQ_IO_THREADS, io_threads_);
    ZMQ_ASSERT (rc == 0);

    rc = zmq_ctx_set (ptr, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS, max_sockets_);
    ZMQ_ASSERT (rc == 0);
}
```

**Update 2**

For further clarification I delved deeper into the zmq source, it appears that the second line is calling

```
int zmq_ctx_set (void *ctx_, int option_, int optval_)
{
    if (!ctx_ || !((zmq::ctx_t*) ctx_)->check_tag ()) {
        errno = EFAULT;
        return -1;
    }
return ((zmq::ctx_t*) ctx_)->set (option_, optval_);
}
```

Which in turn calls

```
int zmq::ctx_t::set (int option_, int optval_)
{
    int rc = 0;
    if (option_ == ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS && optval_ >= 1 && optval_ == clipped_maxsocket (optval_)) {
        opt_sync.lock ();
        max_sockets = optval_;
        opt_sync.unlock ();
    }
    else
    if (option_ == ZMQ_IO_THREADS && optval_ >= 0) {
        opt_sync.lock ();
        io_thread_count = optval_;
        opt_sync.unlock ();
    }
    else
    if (option_ == ZMQ_IPV6 && optval_ >= 0) {
       opt_sync.lock ();
       ipv6 = (optval_ != 0);
       opt_sync.unlock ();
    }
    else {
       errno = EINVAL;
       rc = -1;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

which is failing the first if statement and falls through to the else and returns -1. It appears that the clipped_maxsocket function is not returning 1024 as expected and searching for that function reveals

```
int clipped_maxsocket(int max_requested)
{
    if (max_requested >= zmq::poller_t::max_fds () && zmq::poller_t::max_fds () != -1)
        max_requested = zmq::poller_t::max_fds () - 1;      // -1 because we need room  for the repear mailbox.

    return max_requested;
}
```

**Update 3**
The closest function I could find to the zmq_poller_t::max_fds is i hte poll.cpp file and looks like

```
int zmq::poll_t::max_fds ()
{
    return -1;
}
```

I am not sure if the function above is the right one. If it is the error must be somewhere else because the clipped_maxsocket function will return what it is given.

Comment: Show the code where the assertion is failing in C++ but passing in C. That way we can see what is happening. Any other attempts to answer would just blind guesses.

Comment: You compile .c files or change them to .cpp?

Comment: @sabbahillel I added the information you requested

Comment: You said that the second assertion is the one that is failing. Note that rc = zmq_ctx_set (ptr, ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS, max_sockets_); calls with three arguments while int zmq::ctx_t::set (int option_, int optval_) only has two arguments. This means that you have identified the wrong source code of ctx_t. While C++ allows the multiple definitions, C did not and probably had a different name. You need to find the actual ctx_set that is being called.

Comment: I have updated the trace, I still can't find what is going wrong.

Comment: option_ == ZMQ_MAX_SOCKETS appears to be true in the second call. As a result, the error would appear to be in the value being set for optval_ which is max_sockets_ Is context_t being called with a value or is it using the default value of 1024? What is the value of  clipped_maxsocket (optval_)

Comment: It is being called with the default value, I can't find the maxfds function or poller_t in the code to check further.

Comment: I modified the code to 'zmq::context_t context (1, 1023);' and it works as expected. If I put in 'zmq::context_t context (1, 1024);' it breaks.