# How to build zeromq with MinGW?

Tags: dll, build, mingw, zeromq

I've tried official [howto](http://zeromq.org/build%3amingw) but failed. I got error:

`"The procedure entry point InterlockedCompareExchange@12 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll"`

Answer (score 3):

The problem was due the old `gcc` compiler, bundled with DevKit from rubyinstaller.org (4.5 vs 4.8 on my PC). Use [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) instead. Assume we have zeromq source inside `D:\libs\zeromq`, then the procedure is:

1. Download GUI MinGW installer.
2. Install base and MSYS (if you already have working gcc compiler you probably only need MSYS).
3. Launch MSYS environment by executing `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`.
4. Follow *Using MSYS with MinGW* section:

   1. `mount c:/mingw /mingw`
   2. `cd /d/libs/zeromq`
   3. `./configure --prefix=/mingw`
   4. `make`
   5. Copy `/d/libs/zeromq/src/.libs/libzmq.dll` to your desired place.

In fact I needed to use ZeroMQ with C++, so I downloaded `zmq.hpp`, moved it to include directory, and compiled [`hwserver.cpp`](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C++/hwserver.cpp) to test it:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -o hwserver hwserver.cpp -L. -lzmq -ID:\libs\zeromq\include
```

It worked, but when I launch it I got:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: D:\tmp\zmq\hwserver.exe
File: D:\libs\zeromq\include/zmq.hpp, Line 280

Expression: rc == 0

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I've managed to get rid of this failure by commenting lines 279, 280. [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335467/zmq-hpp-fails-assertion-when-attempting-to-debug)